Vitest, async await, - The error was thrown, while Vitest was running this test
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { screen } from "@testing-library/dom";
import MultiSelect from "@/components/multiselect/multiselect";
import { describe, it, expect, test } from "vitest";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import mockOptions from "./multiselect.mocks";

const initialValues = ["option1"];

describe("<MultiSelect />", () => {
  it("renders correctly with initial values", () => {
    render(
      <MultiSelect
        options={mockOptions}
        defaultValue={initialValues}
        onValueChange={() => {}}
      />
    );

    expect(screen.getByText("Option 1")).toBeDefined();
  });

  test("exist a button to open the dropdown", () => {
    render(
      <MultiSelect
        options={mockOptions}
        defaultValue={[]}
        onValueChange={() => {}}
      />
    );
    const button = screen.getByTestId("multiselect-button-open");
    expect(button).toBeDefined();
  });

  function setup(jsx: React.ReactElement) {
    return {
      user: userEvent.setup(),
      ...render(jsx),
    };
  }

  test("opens dropdown when clicked", async () => {
    const { user } = setup(
      <MultiSelect
        options={mockOptions}
        defaultValue={initialValues}
        onValueChange={() => {}}
      />
    );

    const button = screen.getByTestId("multiselect-button-open");
    expect(button).toBeDefined();
    if (!button) return;
    await user.click(button);
    // expect(screen.getAllByTestId("multiselect-options"));
    expect(screen.getByText("Option 1")).toBeDefined();
  });
});

The error:
This error originated in "src/components/multiselect/multiselect.test.tsx" test file. It doesn't mean the error was thrown inside the file itself, but while it was running.
The latest test that might've caused the error is "opens dropdown when clicked". It might mean one of the following:

The error was thrown, while Vitest was running this test.
If the error occurred after the test had been completed, this was the last documented test before it was thrown.

When I insert async await this error always appears
